# Laravel, Revolution Slider - Error when trying to embed

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, revolution-slider

I am trying to add Revolution Slider to my Laravel instance (per instructions from its creators), and so far, I am getting the following error.

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Argument 2 passed to
>   Illuminate\Translation\Translator::get() must be of the type array,
>   string given, called in
>   /home/sasha/Documents/OffProjects/VetPartnersPrintPortal/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php
>   on line 878 (View:
>   /home/sasha/Documents/OffProjects/VetPartnersPrintPortal/project/resources/views/home/index.blade.php)

The setup is quite simple (basic instructions).

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home/index');
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?php
    include(app_path() . '/Slider/embed.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Example of Revslider embedding</title>
    <?php RevSliderEmbedder::headIncludes(); ?>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- change "example" in the code below to match your slider's alias -->
    <?php
        RevSliderEmbedder::putRevSlider('test');
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Revolution Slider is a Wordpress plugin, pretty sure it won't work with Laravel. If  you [click the revolution-slider tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revolution-slider)  on your question, you'll see that all other questions also have `wordpress` tag attached to them. I would recommend using sliders designed for Laravel, like [this one](https://github.com/Edofre/laravel-slider-pro) or [this one](https://github.com/webelightdev/laravel-slider).

Comment: Wrong. Revslider has a visual editor that works perfectly with PHP. Check it out

Answer (score 0):

Pavel Lint was wrong. The `wordpress` and all yours plugin was developed in `php`, `js` and `mysql`. And the `laravel` is a framework for `php`...

Why the plugins wont work... I use the same revolution sliver in my projects and this work fine. Is this line of js script just include the "@" before `param1, title and param2 like this @{{param1}} |` .

This is solve the problem. Enjoy!